# Нужна помощь по node.js сделать событие на onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Что я ту делаю не правильно?

```
<div class="description">
    <a href="#" class="l-side" onclick="lox"><div id="1" class="block">I want</div></a>
    <a href="#" class="r-side" onclick="loxy"><div id="2" class="hide">Community</div></a>
</div>
<div id="1" class="filter_block" style="display: block">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!-- List group -->
        <ul class="list-group filter_list">
            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="tag in tags">
                {{tag.title}}
                <div class="checkbox_block">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>            
</div>
<div id="2" class="filter_block" style="display: none">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!-- List group -->
        <ul class="list-group filter_list">
            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="tag in tags">
                {{tag.title}}
                <div class="checkbox_block">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>            
</div>

function clickText() {
    objdiv = document.getElementById('1');
    if (objdiv.style.display == "none")
        objdiv.style.display = "block";
    else (obdiv = document.getElementById('2') {
        if (obdiv.style.display == "none")
            obdiv.style.display = "block";
    })
}
```

Comment: а что не работает?

Comment: Я хочу сделать логику чтобы при нажатии одной кнопки скрывался какой та контент и показывалась другая и наоборот при нажатии другой срывалась первая

Comment: Разве это ответ на мой вопрос?

Comment: Всё не работает в коде

Comment: Я в этом пока новичок и не понимаю как сделать такое

Comment: какое к этому имеет отношение  node.js?

Comment: я делал его на node.js приложении

Comment: у меня не получилось поставить его

Comment: У вас в функции, в else нет закрывающей скобки, но есть ненужная на предпоследней строке. Используйте валидатор

Comment: Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function clickText(toHide, toShow) {
  document.getElementById(toHide).style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById(toShow).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  test 1 test 1 test 1
  <button onclick="clickText('div1','div2')">Click 1</button>
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">
  test 2 test 2 test 2
  <button onclick="clickText('div2','div1')">Click 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Как быть с кодом я ведь сейчас туп как спичка

Comment: Работает спасибо